# eBook Publishing Formats?

Tags: html, publish, kindle, nook

I am curious as to how to convert Word Documents and or Adobe PDF Documents into various eBook Formats (hence, Kindle, Nook, iPad, Sony Table, etc.). I have learned that some of these formats required knowledge of HTML and JavaScript. I do know HTML and a little bit of JavaScript, but I would like to know where I need to begin to start converting a Microsoft Word Document and or an Adobe PDF File into the various formats listed above.

Is there a website with a step-by-step process in which this is obtained? Is there any information that I and or the StackOverflow Community can benefit from when it comes to this process? Do I need any specific Programs/Software?

The questions may seem long, but I cannot find anything on this matter anywhere. I assume companies do not want the information on how to do this yourself out on the internet?

Thank you so much, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Aaron

Comment: You might try taking a look at the source code for Calibre. It's an Open source ebook manager that has built-in conversion libraries for converting from Word,PDF, Mobi, ePUb and most of the other formats to almost all ebook formats. Here's [a link](http://calibre-ebook.com/)

Comment: @JamieTaylor should this be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Oh, well. It's been added as an answer now. !!for the community!! :ahem:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Jamie Taylor said Calibre has code that allows conversion however I don't think you're looking to program a conversion software, so just download and install Calibre and use it to convert to all the ebook formats you need.